# Issue while adding a job in APScheduler(Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.6, apscheduler

I am trying to schedule my python script (merchant.py) once a week using [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html)

For this purpose, I have installed the package and when I run the following example code with cronjob option-

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
def tick():
print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'cron', day_of_week = 'mon', hour = 11)
    scheduler.start()
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

I am getting following error-

KeyError: 'cron'

LookupError: No trigger by the name "cron" was found

Could you please correct me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution so sharing for others-

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.combining import OrTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
import time

sched = BlockingScheduler()

trigger = OrTrigger([
   CronTrigger(day_of_week='thu', hour='07', minute='28')
])
sched.add_job(YOUR_JOB, trigger)
sched.start()
try:
    while True:
    time.sleep(2)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    sched.shutdown()
```